First time feral cat owner with kittens
We have been feeding and loving our feral cat and her boyfriend kitty for about a year now. She had kittens about 6-7 weeks ago and she has moved them twice (we know both locations) should at this point the kittens be coming out of hiding and following mom? It’s been about 2 weeks since she’s moved them last and we haven’t seen them since. I’m just hoping that they are still alive and if she’s still nursing or has she stop nursing and have they died from starvation cause they don’t ever come out? We’ve never really heard them cry much so we don’t know where to look under the shed they are hiding under. Mom was very protective of them when we saw them last but now mom is always hanging out on the porch away from them. I’m just curious if this is normal, is everything ok or is it possible she shewed them away at this young of an age? That we know of this is her second litter, her first she only had one and it was during a cold spell and it didn’t make it but this round she had 4 healthy fluffy babies. I have googled just about everything I can and it doesn’t really tell me what I’m looking for so I’m looking for some useful tips and advice.

Yes, after 6-7 weeks the kittens should be big enough to come out and start to discover their environment.
If you do not see or hear anything of them, and their mum does not seem to care any more, they are most probably dead.
You write that they were hidden under a shed. Are there any other animals that have access? A dog perhaps? Wild animals? Or even their father? All of them could be dangerous for the kittens.
Edit: The fact that she moved the kittens twice shows that she had already sensed some threat before. There must be something that made her think that the kittens were in danger.
As I said, it is even possible that the father of the kittens killed them.
